# Can I get the power calculation for one-sample z-test in SAS?

Tags: sas

I already got the power calculation(0.421) for one-sample t-test in SAS, by the following program.
And in z-test, I can get it by proc power in SAS? maybe, the answer would be 0.64058.

```
*t-test ;
proc power; 
onesamplemeans
mean = 1 
stddev = 1.5 
ntotal = 9
alpha = 0.05
power = .; 
run;

*0.421;

***************************;
*z-test ;
data test;
MU_A=6;
MU_B=7;
SD=1.5;
N=9;
ZALPHA=probit(0.95);
MU=MU_A+ZALPHA*SD/sqrt(N);
ZBETA=(MU-MU_B)/(SD/sqrt(N));
POWER=1-probnorm(ZBETA);
run;

*0.64058;
```

Comment: I don't think that exists, and tbh, it's not something that would ever be used except as an academic exercise, but that can easily be accomplished in a data step as you've shown.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I think so too... in R, I could get it "powerZtest()", maybe.

Comment: You can technically do it, you shouldn't do it.